# Get Image Serving Url from Google Cloud Java client libraries

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Image service serving url from AppEngine can be received using the following code.

```
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder
        .withGoogleStorageFileName("/gs/" + bucket + "/image.jpeg")
        .secureUrl(true);
String url = imagesService.getServingUrl(options);
```

How to get image serving Url through Google Cloud Java client library?

[Github Link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java) doesn't give much information about Image services. Is this been supported?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your image is public.  blob.getMediaLink() will print the image url.

```
    StorageOptions options = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
            .setCredentials(GCP_CREDENTIALS).build();
    Storage storage = options.getService();
    Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, IMAGE_FILE_NAME);
    String imageURL = blob.getMediaLink();
```